# Does EBSCO's "Peer Review" search filter filter out junk journals?

Tags: literature-search, disreputable-publishers, digital-libraries

My school's library e-journal search tool uses EBSCO. In EBSCO, one can select "Peer Review" to only show articles from peer reviewed journals. Does this filter have a system for removing junk journals (i.e. journals that receive money to publish work) from the search results or will many junk journals calling themselves peer-reviewed journals still manage to get through the filter?

Comment: Not every journal that receives money to publish is junk. PLoS Biology is for example a well respected journal.

Comment: I'll also add that peer review filter simply restrict the search to peer reviewed articles. What is **junk** is subjective. Non peer reviewed doesn't mean junk, it simply means _non peer reviewed_. See the details of EBSCO peer review definitions in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

However, keep in mind the various (read: broad) definitions of what *peer reviewed* means. EBSCO uses following [definitions](http://support.epnet.com/knowledge_base/detail.php?id=976):

> **Blind Peer Reviewed** - (or Double Blind Peer Reviewed) - Articles appearing in a journal are sent outside of the journal's publishing or sponsoring organization for review by external reviewer(s), whereby the either author's identity or the reviewers' identity is unknown.
>
> **Editorial Board Peer Review** - articles appearing in a journal are reviewed by an internal board of editors, not solely by one editor. The author's identity may be known or unknown.
>
> **Expert Peer Review** - articles appearing in a journal are reviewed by experts (either internal or external to the journal) whose credentials are known and who are experts within the subject matter of the article under review. The author's identity may be known or unknown.

According to EBSCO, you can also restrict your search to peer reviewed articles by suffixing your query with **AND RV Y**.